# What is a more elegant way to do a check on and assign a string permutation?

Tags: c#, string

The usecase: I want to check if a string has whitespaces at the end, and if it does, replace the string with the same string except for the whitespaces, plus write a log. My first instinct tells me that

```
if(someString.Trim() != someString)
{
    someString= someString.Trim();
    Log("whitespaces trimmed");
}
```

would be a way to do so. However, in this case I trim the string twice, which seems unneccessary to me.

So I thought of

```
 var trimString = someString.Trim();
 if (trimString != someString) 
 {
    someString = trimString;
    Log("whitespaces trimmed");
 }
```

However, this introduces a basically useless variable. It may get gc'ed later on, but it is still ugly in my opinion. So, I thought of using, well, "using", but the compiler quickly reminded me that string doesnt implement IDisposable.

So, my question is: Is there a more elegant way to write these kinds of scenarios?

Comment: Why just don't use `var trimString = someString.Trim();` without any `if` conditions?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski The OP only wants to log if there's a space at the end of the string, hence the check

Comment: The second option is perfectly viable. Yes, there's a useless variable, but it's really premature optimization. The compiler possibly optimizes it away anyway. Using IDisposable would have probably introduced more overhead than a simple temporary variable.

Comment: Could you use string.Contains(" ") to determine if there's a space? Also I believe Trim() only remove leading and trailing white-space, so you may need to consider this.

Comment: @RyanThomas id the user is writing a sentence, paragraph etc your test would always be true and read false positives. So a check on the beginning and end would be best placed. For me, the first option would be the better option, but can see why others would pick the second

Comment: This is also a very opinion based answer, everyone has their own styles on how to do things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally go with `EndsWith`:

```
if (someString.EndsWith(" "))
{
    someString = someString.Trim();
    Log("whitespaces trimmed");
}
```

This will check whether the last character of the string is a space (hence, it needs to be trimmed).  Then, and only then, is the end of the string itself actually trimmed.

Saves on the overhead of trimming twice.

**Edit after some thinking time**

I had a further think about this.  OP mentioned *whitespace* specifically, not just spaces.

Here's some code that checks for whitespace at the last character of the string:

```
if (char.IsWhiteSpace(someString[someString.Length - 1]))
{
    someString = someString.Trim();
    Log("whitespaces trimmed");
}
```

This again saves the overhead of an extra `Trim` when it may not be needed.

Comment: that is assuming that the string is not null or empty

Comment: @Slai You're right, it's based on the OP's code from the question in which it is already implied that the string is not null or empty (through the use of `.Trim()`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
      string someString = "Test ";
      string val = someString.EndsWith(" ") ? TrimAndLog(someString)  : someString ;
      public string TrimAndLog(string someThing)
      {
            someThing = someThing.Trim(); //Trim will Trim all leading and Trailing whitespaces, You should use method TrimEnd
            Log("whitespaces trimmed");
            return someThing;
      }
```